# Serving 2 servers on one domain/port pair

Tags: nginx, webserver, flask, uwsgi

I have some static HTML/Javascript/CSS files that I'd like to serve at `/`.
But I also have a webserver that performs all of my API calls written in Python using Flask and uwsgi.
What I'm trying to do is to have all of my static content be accessible as localhost and my web API be accessible through localhost/api.

This is my default site in sites-enabled:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www;

    location /api {
        location / {
            try_files $uri @app;
        }

        location @app {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm serving static content located at `/var/www` and I'm trying to make all requests to `/api` to be handled by uwsgi..
Currently when I try this, uwsgi gives me 404 and I think that it is because the uwsgi parameters aren't being passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather of the documentation (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/uwsgi/), the method you choose only works when the app is set to the URL root.  I removed the try_files from your /api location as I do not believe it is needed since you are not serving static files from there.  You may not need the rewrite either.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404
    }

    location = /api { rewrite ^ /api/; }
    location /api {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /api;
        uwsgi_modifier1 30;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
    }
```